# Won't standby, usb_bluetooth refusing to freeze

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, bluetooth

I am running Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca on a Yoga Pro laptop. The laptop will only go into standby once and then will not until it is restarted. When attempting to standby it will freeze for 20 seconds and then come back up. 
Running `pm-suspend` on the command line shows no output. `dmesg` has some useful logs. The relevent part is below

```
[60991.396195] Freezing user space processes ... 
[61011.412504] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.000 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
[61011.412578] usb_bluetooth   D ffff88025f214440     0 14665  14591 0x00000004
[61011.412581]  ffff88024bbc5b50 0000000000000002 ffff88024dce47d0 ffff88024bbc5fd8
[61011.412584]  0000000000014440 0000000000014440 ffff88024dce47d0 ffff8802515a6c80
[61011.412586]  ffff8802515a6c84 ffff88024dce47d0 00000000ffffffff ffff8802515a6c88
[61011.412588] Call Trace:
[61011.412594]  [<ffffffff8171a3a9>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
[61011.412596]  [<ffffffff8171c215>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x135/0x1b0
[61011.412598]  [<ffffffff8171c2af>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x2f
[61011.412601]  [<ffffffff81532a54>] usb_unlocked_disable_lpm+0x24/0x50
[61011.412603]  [<ffffffff81534f48>] usb_port_suspend+0x128/0x440
[61011.412606]  [<ffffffff8154a55a>] generic_suspend+0x2a/0x40
[61011.412608]  [<ffffffff815413df>] usb_suspend_both+0x1bf/0x1e0
[61011.412610]  [<ffffffff815425d3>] usb_runtime_suspend+0x33/0x70
[61011.412613]  [<ffffffff815425a0>] ? usb_probe_interface+0x2f0/0x2f0
[61011.412615]  [<ffffffff8149a166>] __rpm_callback+0x36/0xc0
[61011.412617]  [<ffffffff811d9074>] ? mntput+0x24/0x40
[61011.412619]  [<ffffffff8149a214>] rpm_callback+0x24/0x80
[61011.412620]  [<ffffffff8149a396>] rpm_suspend+0x126/0x6e0
[61011.412622]  [<ffffffff8149ba5d>] __pm_runtime_suspend+0x5d/0x80
[61011.412625]  [<ffffffff81542630>] ? usb_runtime_resume+0x20/0x20
[61011.412627]  [<ffffffff8154265a>] usb_runtime_idle+0x2a/0x40
[61011.412628]  [<ffffffff8149a166>] __rpm_callback+0x36/0xc0
[61011.412630]  [<ffffffff8149abfd>] rpm_idle+0x1bd/0x2b0
[61011.412631]  [<ffffffff8149b86d>] pm_runtime_allow+0x8d/0x90
[61011.412634]  [<ffffffff8149426a>] control_store+0xca/0xd0
[61011.412636]  [<ffffffff81489ab8>] dev_attr_store+0x18/0x30
[61011.412639]  [<ffffffff8122f418>] sysfs_write_file+0x128/0x1c0
[61011.412643]  [<ffffffff811b9534>] vfs_write+0xb4/0x1f0
[61011.412644]  [<ffffffff811b9f69>] SyS_write+0x49/0xa0
[61011.412647]  [<ffffffff8172663f>] tracesys+0xe1/0xe6
[61011.412654] 
[61011.412654] Restarting tasks ... done.
```

Output of `ps aux | grep blue`

```
root     14665  0.0  0.0   4440   716 ?        D    15:20   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/usb_bluetooth true
```

I have tried both:
`rfkill block bluetooth` and `service bluetooth stop` and have added them both to `/etc/rc.local` with no effect.

And I also added `blacklist btusb` and `blacklist bluetooth` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

None of these seem to work as the usb_bluetooth task still starts and the laptop won't go into standby.

I have also tried `apt-get purge libgnome-bluetooth11`, but this tries to remove `network-manager-gnome` for some reason.....

It would be nice if bluetooth worked, but I just want to put my computer on standby.... come on...