# How can tasks "refuse to freeze" on suspend?

Tags: debian, kill, suspend

Yesterday, when closing my laptop, it did not go into standby mode immediately. According to the logs, it was trying to, but a tasks refused to freeze:

```
Freezing of tasks failed after 20.005 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
```

This went on for a few hours until the system actually suspended. The `syslog` was full of messages like in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237837/wont-standby-usb-bluetooth-refusing-to-freeze), because `systemd` was trying again and again.

How can this happen? Why can't the scheduler just stop scheduling that application? and then it's effectively frozen? I read that there are multiple `STOP` commands, one of them asking nicely and one of them forcing freeze. Why did `systemd` not use this or why did this not work here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Task freezing is documented in detail [in the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/power/freezing-of-tasks.html).

User-space processes can’t refuse to freeze; they do get frozen, but the signalling between the kernel and processes is handled automatically by the signal-handling code (freezing uses a fake signal).

If you’re seeing “tasks refusing to freeze” messages, that means that a kernel thread is refusing to freeze, usually because it’s doing something which can’t be checkpointed. However having to wait several hours for the kernel to suspend isn’t normal; the stack traces in the log messages would help to get some idea of what’s going wrong.